# Understanding an AttributeError in python and how to solve it

Tags: python

I am getting the error :

```
    data = cipher.encrypt(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Crypto/Cipher/PKCS1_OAEP.py", line 133, in encrypt
    randFunc = self._key._randfunc
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_randfunc'
```

in my console for the following section of code:

```
  cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(PK_ID)
  data = cipher.encrypt(data)
```

both the PK_ID and data are both of Str

what does the error message mean and how can i solve it for this code?

Answer (score 1):

The `PKCS1_OAEP.new()` function takes an RSA key object, which you can get from the `Crypto.PublicKey.RSA` module, it doesn't take a `str`.

Comment: So i would need to pass an 'instance' to the PKCS1_OAEP.new() function ?, is there anyway to convert the PK_ID to this for it to be acepted ?